# Reduce the amount of getter and setter calls from class

Tags: php, oop, getter-setter

This is probably a stupid question but I can't figure out what to google. I'm learning OOP and get the general concept but trying to implement it and I'm getting some questions.

I'm making a web scraper using simple html dom. I want to create a class which connects to a page and contains several different functions I can call on that page depending on what I want to do. I then can call this classes methods from another file.

This is the class I have written:

```
<?php

include_once '/simple_html_dom.php';

class CountyScraping
{
protected $demoMode = 0; //set 1 for demo
protected $cinemas = NULL;
protected $url = NULL;
protected $html = NULL;
protected $counties = array();

function __construct($url)
{
    $this->setUrl($url);
}

public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;
}

public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->url;
}

public function setHtml()
{
    $this->html = file_get_html($this->url);
}

public function getHtml()
{
    return $this->html;
}

public function setCounties()
{
    foreach($this->html->find('#UserLocation option') as $element)
    {
        if (($element->value != NULL) && ($element->plaintext))
        {   
            $county = array();
            $county['id'] = $element->value;
            $county['county_name'] = $element->plaintext;
            $this->counties[] = $county;
        }
    }
}

public function getCounties()
{
    return $this->counties;
}

?>
```

As you can see from the class above I'm looking to get a list of counties from my page and it's all working as should be. The main method I want to call is to get an array of counties. Using the code above to get a list of counties I have to do something like this currently:

```
$scrape = new CountyScraping("http://example.com");

$scrape->setHtml();
$scrape->setCounties();
$counties = $scrape->getCounties();
```

This works fine and I could continue with this however I feel like I'm making a lot of calls to getters and setters from outside the class. I think I should be making one call, getCounties and have everything be handled inside the class.

Am I correct in assuming this? Should my getCounties() method call my setHtml and setCounties methods? Or should I be keeping my getters and setters as minimal as possible and have another function instead?

Any advice about any part of my code would be welcome.

Comment: At first place: split the job of fetching page from job of parsing it. They are independent. Second: you don't need to use setters internally. Third: from API point of view - `setHtml` and `setCountries` methods look weird.

Comment: You should be using the getters and setters within the `getCounties()` method. It is usually best to keep the use of your getters and setters outside of the class to a minimum. Instead, manipulate the object using it's methods.

Comment: In the Yii framework, setter and getter functions are provided by inheritance. Take a look at Yii and maybe adapt the strategy used. Find more info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-properties.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP magic methods will help you a bit more also.
Here is a link to the php manual for `__set()`
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

here is also a nice articale that will assist you with more information on magic methods
http://culttt.com/2014/04/16/php-magic-methods/

Here is a basic example of magic methods

```
<?php
class PropertyTest
{
    /**  Location for overloaded data.  */
    private $data = array();

    /**  Overloading not used on declared properties.  */
    public $declared = 1;

    /**  Overloading only used on this when accessed outside the class.  */
    private $hidden = 2;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "Setting '$name' to '$value'\n";
        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "Getting '$name'\n";
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$name];
        }

        $trace = debug_backtrace();
        trigger_error(
            'Undefined property via __get(): ' . $name .
            ' in ' . $trace[0]['file'] .
            ' on line ' . $trace[0]['line'],
            E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.1.0  */
    public function __isset($name)
    {
        echo "Is '$name' set?\n";
        return isset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    /**  As of PHP 5.1.0  */
    public function __unset($name)
    {
        echo "Unsetting '$name'\n";
        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    /**  Not a magic method, just here for example.  */
    public function getHidden()
    {
        return $this->hidden;
    }
}


echo "<pre>\n";

$obj = new PropertyTest;

$obj->a = 1;
echo $obj->a . "\n\n";

var_dump(isset($obj->a));
unset($obj->a);
var_dump(isset($obj->a));
echo "\n";

echo $obj->declared . "\n\n";

echo "Let's experiment with the private property named 'hidden':\n";
echo "Privates are visible inside the class, so __get() not used...\n";
echo $obj->getHidden() . "\n";
echo "Privates not visible outside of class, so __get() is used...\n";
echo $obj->hidden . "\n";
?>
```

Output is here:

```
Setting 'a' to '1'
Getting 'a'
1

Is 'a' set?
bool(true)
Unsetting 'a'
Is 'a' set?
bool(false)

1

Let's experiment with the private property named 'hidden':
Privates are visible inside the class, so __get() not used...
2
Privates not visible outside of class, so __get() is used...
Getting 'hidden'


Notice:  Undefined property via __get(): hidden in <file> on line 70 in <file> on line 29
```

This example has been sourced from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set

Comment: As i like properties to read 'things' i use the 'magic' '__get' with checks in it to ensure that only valid 'property type things' can be read. So, a +1 from me. 'set' is not so clear cut as parameters may be needed and other logic may need to be performed.

Comment: I do not understand why using magic methods in that case. Magic methods can sometimes be useful but I would recommend to use them  sparingly. Remember that you should use low coupling (interfaces) between your classes in order to have a scalable, maintenable and testable application. Magic calls prevent to do this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to always use an SOA (service oriented architecture) when you want to develop with OOP. With SOA your service coming from the class `CountyScraper` should be unique. This is why we use a [singleton](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html). A service shouldn't keep a state from an action. This is why you shouldn't set the url or html as properties.

```
<?php

include_once '/simple_html_dom.php';

class CountyScraper
{
    /**
     * Returns the *Singleton* instance of this class.
     *
     * @staticvar Singleton $instance The *Singleton* instances of this class.
     *
     * @return Singleton The *Singleton* instance.
     */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        static $instance = null;
        if (null === $instance) {
            $instance = new static();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Protected constructor to prevent creating a new instance of the
     * *Singleton* via the `new` operator from outside of this class.
     */
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Private clone method to prevent cloning of the instance of the
     * *Singleton* instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __clone()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Private unserialize method to prevent unserializing of the *Singleton*
     * instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function __wakeup()
    {
    }

    public function findCounties($url)
    {
        $counties = array();
        $html = file_get_html($url);

        foreach ($html->find('#UserLocation option') as $element)
        {
            if (($element->value != NULL) && ($element->plaintext))
            {   
                $county = array();
                $county['id'] = $element->value;
                $county['county_name'] = $element->plaintext;
                $counties[] = $county;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it like that:

```
$countyScraper = CountyScraper::getInstance();

$countyScraper->findCounties('http://example.com');
```